# unsigned integer wraparound handling in C

Tags: c

To handle unsigned integer wraparound issues, I am planning to use the following checks.

**Addition:**
Performing a postcondition check to ensure that the result of the unsigned addition operation is not less than the first value

```
void fn(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) 
{
  unsigned int sum = a + b;
  if (sum < a) {
    // Wraparound occured. return error.
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

**Subtraction:** Performing a postcondition test that the result of the unsigned subtraction operation is not greater than the first value:

```
void fn(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) 
{
  unsigned int difference = a - b;
  if (difference > a) {
    // Wraparound occured. return error.
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

I assume these checks will works irrespective of compilers. Is there any better way to handle unsigned integer wraparound issues? I am looking for cross platform support.

Comment: That's about it for _unsigned_ math.

Comment: `better way` - The usuall question: better in what way?  I would name `sum` in the second function `difference`. `sum` is misleading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow)

Comment: In the second case, you could simply check for `a < b` and drop the operation altogether. In the first case, is there any reason why you cannot use a larger type to hold the result?

Comment: @KamilCuk When I searched SO, there are lot of different solutions proposed. I found this approach in SEI CERT C Coding Standard

Comment: @nivpeled That thread is talking about overflow not wraparound

Comment: @th33lf C does not specify wider types exist than `unsigned`.  Example: `unsigned long long` only needs to be at least as wide as `unsigned` and at least 64-bit.  Both could be 64-bit.   Not common but allowed by C.   Your simply `a < b` is very correct.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach for checking whether `z=x+y` will yield an arithmetically-correct value is to compare `x` with `(targetType)~(promotedType)y`, where `(targetType)` is the type of the unsigned target container, and `(promotedType)` is the type with which the addition would be performed.  If `x` exceeds `(targetType)~y`, then the result will not fit in the target type.

To understand the casts, consider that if `y` is 1, then the maximum value for `x` should be one less than the smaller of the maximum value for the type that will receive `x+y`, or the type with which `x+y` would be evaluated.  The inner promotion is needed to accommodate the case where `x` is larger than `y`, and the outer one is needed to accommodate the case where `z` is smaller than the type used for the addition.